# Check if this function injective or surjective $ f(x,y)=[x]_R \cap[y]_R$

Tags: functions, relations

Let $ R \subseteq \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ be an equivalance relation. Function $ f:  \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is describes as $ f(x,y)=[x]_R \cap[y]_R$

1)Check if it is injective.

2)Check if it is surrjective.

3)Find $f^{-1}(([3]_R))$

I can`t quite understand what $[x]_R$ notation means(the index of relation).Can some one explain what relation has to do here?
I think it is not injective beacuse we can change places of x and y.

Comment: $[x]_R$ in this context must mean the $R$-equivalence to which $x$ belongs, i.e., $y\in[x]_R$ iff $(x,y)\in R$.

Comment: basically any equivalence relation partitions the space into disjoint subsets. Those subsets are exactly what we call  "equivalence classes" and they  are described in the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us see that $f$ is not injective, no matter what equivalence relation $R$ is.

Suppose that $R=\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ (the largest equivalence relation on $\mathbb N$).
Then $[n]_R=\mathbb N$, for all $n$, and then $f(n,m)=\mathbb N$, for every $n,m$, and so it's not injective.

Now suppose that $R \neq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.
So there exist at least two equivalence classes of $R$ and one of them is not a singleton.
Let us say that $(x,y) \notin R$ and $(x,y') \notin R$, with $y\neq y'$, but $(y,y') \in R$ and thus, $[y]_R=[y']_R$.
Then
$$f(x,y) = [x]_R \cap [y]_R = [x]_R \cap [y']_R = f(x,y').$$

A similar argument can show it's not surjective.

---

**Edit** (I forgot the last part.)
Clearly,
$$f^{-1}([3]_R)= \{(x,y)\in\mathbb N^2 : f(x,y)=[3]_R\},$$
and that shouldn't be difficult to unfold.

---

**Edit 2.**
I just noticed that the OP claims to think $f$ not injective because

> we can change places of $x$ and $y$.

That is indeed enough, since for $x\neq y$ we have $(x,y)\neq(y,x)$, but $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.
So that makes a shorter proof that $f$ is not injective.

---

**Edit 3.** (OP ask for clarification.)

To show it's not surjective, again, suppose $R=\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, so that $(n,m)\in R$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb N$.
Thus, for all $n$ we have $[n]_R=\mathbb N$, whence $\mathrm{im}(f)=\{\mathbb N\}$.
But $\mathbb N$ is one among (uncountably) infinite elements of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, and so $f$ is not surjective.

On the other hand, if $R\neq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, then for all $n$, the equivalence class $[n]_R$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb N$, and so there exist no $x,y$ such that $[x]_R\cap[y]_R=\mathbb N$, and therefore, $\mathbb N \notin \mathrm{im}(f)$.

(Notice this would work even if we had a two-element set in place of $\mathbb N$.)

For the last part,
\begin{align}
f^{-1}([3]_R)
&= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb N^2 : f(x,y) = [3]_R\right\}\\
&= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb N^2 : [x]_R\cap[y]_R=[3]_R\right\}.
\end{align}
Now notice that two equivalence classes are either equal or disjoint, but $[3]_R \neq \varnothing$ because $3 \in [3]_R$, and so
$$[x]_R\cap[y]_R=[3]_R \iff [x]_R=[y]_R=[3]_R.$$
Hence
$$f^{-1}([3]_R)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb N^2 : x,y\in[3]_R\}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still I didn`t get your solution with that supposition  with  R≠N×N, could you please provide some clarification to that?

Comment: Also could you please unfold the last part with $f^{-1}([3]_\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @Alex About the first comment, is it about $f$ not being injective or is it for the proof that is not surjective?

Comment: About the second one (not beeing surjective)